# is.nan() behavior

Tags: r

Created a data frame:

```
simpleDF<- structure(list(vals = c(NA, NaN, 2)), .Names = "vals", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")


> is.na(simpleDF$vals)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> is.nan(simpleDF$vals)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now, when I change the data frame to include a string value:

```
simpleDF <- structure(list(vals = structure(c(NA, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("2", 
"NaN", "test"), class = "factor")), .Names = "vals", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

> is.na(simpleDF$vals)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> is.nan(simpleDF$vals)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I did not understand why `NaN` is no longer recognized by `is.nan()`? Sure there would be an explanation ..

Comment: It's because you've coerced the column into `factor`. Note `is.numeric(NaN)` is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NaN` is a value that only makes sense in numeric vector, so it gets converted to the character string `"NaN"` when the class of the vector it is in is (explicitly or implicitly) converted from numeric to character or factor.

```
vals
# [1]  NA NaN   2
as.character(vals)
# [1] NA    "NaN" "2" 
c(vals, "A")
# [1] NA    "NaN" "2"   "A"
```

Comment: and the subtle hint is that `"NaN"` ends up in quotation marks after the combination ... while `NA` doesn't ...

Comment: Interesting to see that `as.integer(vals)` also converts `NaN`, as I suppose it should given that `NaN` only (?) arises in forming **ratio**-nal numbers.

Comment: @BenBolker -- Yes, thanks. That's the key bit, and it did need better bringing out.